# getting a 100% between two numbers?

Tags: swift, timer, percentage

I happen to have a timer which keeps track of two different points.
When I start, both are at zero.

when the button is pressed, one of them, let's call it A, keeps on incrementing by 1 every second.
If I press the button again, the state will switch and B variable will now start adding a point every second.

Let's say I have A at 10 and B at 30.
I would like to calculate the % between them.

For this specific case, I'd like a print out that A = 25% and B = 75%.

This is my code so far:

```
var total = A + B
var BPercentage = total - B / 100
var AestPercentage = A/B*100
var damo = 00.00
damo =  100/Double(total/B)
print(damo)
```

None of these seem to work.

Comment: FYI - variable names should start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like the following?

```
var total = A + B
var bPercentage = (B / total) * 100
var aPercentage = (A / total) * 100

var percentageDiff = abs(aPercentage - bPercentage)
```